# Get location from image in Android 12

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-12

I want to fetch location from image. I have used ExifInterface. It's working in Android 9 but not working in Android 12. I have pixel 4A with Android 12. I have added access_media_location permission as well.

```
boolean hasLatLong = false;
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
                        InputStream stream = v.getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imagePickerModel.getUri());
                        if (stream != null) {
                            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(stream);
                            stream.close();
                            hasLatLong= exifInterface.getLatLong() != null;

                        }
                    }else {
                        hasLatLong= exif.getLatLong() != null;
                    }
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this on Android 12?

Comment: yes. actually my camera app doesn't had location permission.

Comment: You mean regular location permission or ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION permission?

Comment: regular permission in camera app and check once in camera app that location is enable or not.